# Get data from submit button, display text file , clear text box

Tags: php, html, text, form-submit

My need is bit more complicated for me, 
but for many it will be easy..

Here is what i want,
in my form i have 3 objects, Textbox, Submit Button, and Display area.

Users have to enter some details in Text Box and to Press Submit button, 
The details have to be displayed in the Display Area (Display Box) which is below.
After Displaying the details the text box must be empty. Users cannot or should not edit the details in display area.

Here is what i had tried,

1. Enter Text , Click Submit button- The data will be saved in Text file1
2. Open the Text file2 in appending mode and add Text file1 into Text file2
3. Display Text file2 , Clear Text file1 (for Next Use)

[image]

Comment: Extra Info - One user can enter any number of data

Comment: i tried php , html too..

Answer (score 0):

```
//view.php
<?php

if (isset($_POST['submit'])
{
$text = $_POST['text1'];
echo $text;
echo "<br />";
}
echo "<form action= '' method='post'>
Text Box: &nbsp; <input type='text' name='text1' />
<input type='submit' name='submit' />
</form>";

?>
```

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '{' in view.php on line 4

Answer (score 0):

Its pretty Basic HTML + Javascript . Anyway here the code :)

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
function display()
{
document.getElementById("displayarea").innerHTML = document.getElementById("myinput").value;    
document.getElementById("myinput").value = "";
}
</script>
</head>

<body>
<input type="text" name="myinput" id="myinput">
<input type="button" value="Submit" name="submit" id="submit" onClick="display()"/>
<div id="displayarea">Sample Text. This data will disappear if you press button</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Nope @ Dipen Baskaran.. i asked append bro.. all your coding is correct ,. but if we enter 123 then submit, it displayed.. (up to this you are great bro..) after that if we enter abcd in textbox and if we click submit, the 123 displayed is vanished, what i need is to display abcd below 123.. that is to append and have to use BR for next line... once again thank you bro Dipen Baskaran..